AWS cloudwatch Log Insight with timeseries and dynamic filter
fields @timestamp, errorData.msg
| filter !isempty(errorData.msg)
| stats count() as Count by errorData.msg, bin(15m)

The line graph should show timeseries as x axis and count as Y axis along errorData.msg as filter of graph . So if we have 10 unique errorData.msg then we should see 10 filter in graph.
With above query I am not getting expected output.
